# Deployment to JBoss/WildFly 8 fails with Java heap space

Tags: java, jenkins, jboss, wildfly-8

My Jenkins build fails sometimes while deploying to JBoss/WildFly 8 with Java heap space problem.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha2:deploy (default-cli) on project Prometheus: Deployment failed: Operation failed: "JBAS014749: Operation handler failed: Java heap space" -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

I have to restart my JBoss/WildFly every time this happens to deploy to server. Please help me in clearing the problem so that it doesn't hinder my automation.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? And, you probably need to start it with more heap space.

Comment: Java 1.8.0_25, where should I change heap space?

Comment: You'll want to add a [`javaOpts`](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/start-mojo.html) and specify a `-Xmx` and `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` (both take numeric values specified by an equal sign followed by the value and then a size suffix, `=1g` and `=1024m` are the same). As for an appropriate size, there you'll need to be guided by your machines memory limits.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you, but can you please specify where and how can I add javaopts.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 
 
I've changed to these values, but still we are facing problem JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"